# joomla 3.0 template creation

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Can anyone give me link or guidance about where I can learn creating a Joomla 3.0 template for free . I know html ,css and php .
I read a pdf file by Jessica Barte but realized that it was for earlier version of joomla and the template I made was not working .

Comment: [Here](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/08/create-joomla-template-from-scratch.html) is a tutorial for creating a joomla 3  template from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out below link and let me know if you have any issues

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/create-template

Answer (score 1):

Read the official documentation (for any version):

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template